# Why is Vue Material throwing Unknown custom element?

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vue-material

I have the following code...

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'
import 'vue-material/dist/theme/default.css'
import App from './app/App.vue';
Vue.use(VueMaterial)
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App },
    template: '<App/>'
});
```

But when I try to use the drawer like this...

```
 <md-table>
    <md-table-row>
        <md-table-head md-numeric>ID</md-table-head>
        <md-table-head>Name</md-table-head>
        <md-table-head>Email</md-table-head>
        <md-table-head>Gender</md-table-head>
        <md-table-head>Job Title</md-table-head>
    </md-table-row>
 </md-table>
```

I get...

> Unknown custom element: `<md-table>` - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

And nothing renders.

Comment: Are you using `vue-cli`? What does your app structure look like? I wasn't able to reproduce this error, although using your code, I had to change `import App from './app/App.vue';` to `import App from './App.vue';` Is this code on GitHub?

Comment: No I am using a straight express app

Comment: How does your code differ from this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8kwmo8w6l9)?